# Divide website into vertical columns and give separate colours to each

Tags: html, css

I can divide a page into sections and give them separate colour using css   as

```
.window:nth-child(1) {
background: #d5d7dd;
top: 0%;
}
.window:nth-child(2) {
background: #1babb7;
top: 100%;
}
```

Can I divide one of these 'child' into different columns and give them separate colour?
[image: Like the third row is divided into 2 coumns]

Comment: Post some HTML to show how you are creating your columns.

Comment: Yes, use the same approach, if you don't understand how the CSS is working for the main sections then I suggest you figure that out first

Comment: Has per user @MarcAudet mentioned, without html, trying to help you is close to useless. Actually, this looks like homework to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged HTML & CSS with this question, so here's some basic code to demonstrate how to create this.

Note: It seems you're new to HTML & CSS, so I encourage you to do some tutorials!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
#one {
    width:33.333%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
#two {
    width:33.333%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#three {
    width:33.333%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: what the 'float' is for?

Comment: It helps the three containers sit side-by-side: "With CSS float, an element can be pushed to the left or right, allowing other elements to wrap around it." [More Info on Floats](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)